# SAP ERP, how to checkIn document files?

Tags: document, sap-erp, saprfc, bapi, function-module

I want to create a new document in SAP ERP. Additional I have some files which belongs to this document, these files I want to upload to the SAP knowledge base.

I'm using `BAPI_DOCUMENT_CREATE2` to create or `BAPI_DOCUMENT_CHECKIN2` to add files to a document info data. Every thing works fine, except file upload or checkin.

I'm using the `DOCUMENTFILES` table. I add a row for each file, currently I set only three fields:

```
  row["STORAGECATEGORY"] = "DMS_C1_ST";
  row["DOCFILE"] = "c:\temp\bom.pdf";
  row["WASAPPLICATION"] = "PDF";
```

BAPI error message:

> Error while checking in and storing c:/temp/bom.pdf

I set the parameter

```
  PF_FTP_DEST = "SAPFTPA";
  PF_HTTP_DEST = "SAPHTTPA";
```

I have looked in the log data (`slg1`). I found following entry:

> ERRMSG: Error in opening file "..." for reading (No such file or directory)
>
> ```
> V1:     SCMS_DOC_CREATE_FILES
> V2:     13
> ```

It would be nice if anybody has an idea and could bring some light in this issue.
Thanks in advance
Thomas

Answer (score 1):

Remember that BAPIS run inside the application server and are not allowed to make any assumptions about the client side. This also means that they can't call back to the SAP GUI and upload a file from there. C:\temp\bom.pdf has to be a file on the application server, not your local machine!

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using

```
row["DOCFILE"] = "bom.pdf";
row["DOCPATH"] = "c:\temp\";
```

Let me know how it goes, or if you have already done with it then please paste your solution.